# How to let users register using their social networking account?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I have a register page in my mobile app that I am building using (PhoneGap Api) HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript. I am planning to let users register using their facebook or gmail account. I am not sure how does that work any help/tips/tutorial links to accomplish that task on my webpage would be great ?

Comment: Look into [OpenID](http://openid.net/).

Comment: To clarify: OAuth2 is a more powerful replacement for OpenID. OpenID is a good place to start. However, some services - including Google and Facebook - have retired OpenID in favor of OAuth2 because it is far more extensible. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use OAuth2 to accomplish this. OAuth2 is a standarized method of using login data from various sites like Facebook, Microsoft, Google, Yahoo, and AOL (all of the above support OAuth2).

The basic idea is that you redirect the user to the login service's URL, providing the necessary data (like an API key and a session ID), the service logs in the user and prompts them to authorize your application to use their data, and the service then redirects the user back to your site along with appropriate data to verify the user against your application (usually an email address or unique user GUID).

Each service's specific details are going to be different, so you need to look at the individual documentation for the OAuth2 implementation for each site that you want to support. You can use a prebuilt library to do all this, but I'd discourage against that, mostly because if you use a third-party library, you're beholden to that library's developer(s) to maintain and update it, whereas if you write the code yourself, you can learn a lot more about what you're doing and can maintain it yourself.

I'd recommend the articles on [this site](http://blog.abettergeek.com/tag/google-oauth2/) for a detailed description with code samples of implementing Google OAuth2 support using C#.